# Python-Django: user info in template

Tags: python, django, templates

I have database, currently from my database its displaying like this in my Template(HTML table) page.

```
sno--scene--frames--empID

1------001----24-----100

2------002----34-----100

3------003----20-----101

4------004----15-----101

5------005----10-----100
```

But i want to display like this(below). How to get this from `HTML`(tables). I am using Python-Django.

```
sno---scene---frames---empID

1--------001-----24-------100

2--------002-----34-------100

3--------005-----10-------100

------------- tot=68

1------003-----20--------101

2------004-----15--------101

-------------tot=35
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare the data in a view - group them by id, calculate sum. Result cal looks like this:

```
items_info = [{'items':[item1, item2, item3], 'total': 68}, {'items':[item4, item5], 'total': 35}]
```

Then template should be like this:

```
{% for info in items_info %}
    {% for item in info.items %}
        <tr> 
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.scene }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.frames }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">TOTAL</td>
        <td>{{ info.total }}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps!